# detect English words and nltk's words corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Just trying to see of a word is English or not. This:

```
english_words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
print("revised" in english_words)
```

results in False. Am I doing something wrong? Is this to be expected? Are there better ways of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Dumb question, but did you check if the word revised is actually in the corpus?

Comment: which corpus - english_words or mine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449284/nltk-words-corpus-does-not-contain-okay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that "revised" indeed is not in the wordlist:

```
import nltk

english_words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

for w in english_words:
    if w.startswith("revise"):
        print(w)
```

prints the following list:

```
reviser
revise
revisee
revisership
```

Based on [this source](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html), section 4.1, this is where the word list originates from:

> The Words Corpus is the /usr/share/dict/words file from Unix

So you'll have to decide for your use case if the provided word list from NLTK is enough or if you want to switch to a more complete (and bigger) one.

Comment: I think you should also lemmatize your word, then you'll find it in the English words

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

if not wordnet.synsets(word_to_test):
  #Not an English Word
else:
  #English Word
```